# How do I determine the function from its graphic?

Tags: functions

[image: How do I determine the function from it's graphic?]

How am I supposed to know the function from it's graphic?

Answer (score 2):

We can't find in general the correct expression but we can guess some function with a similar graph, in that case it seems similar to

$$f(x)=x^3e^{-|x|}$$

[image]

Comment: which software did you use to graphic

Comment: @AdriánJuárezCarrasquedo Desmos, here is the [LINK](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)

Comment: how do you add values?, mine is lke this